# "without" without object?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, ambiguity

Below is an encrypt from John Lock's "An Essay on Human Understanding".

I am not able to understand the meaning of "without" in this context. The problem is that it's object is not mentioned. I viewed such an instance of "without" in Cambridge Dictionary, i.e,

"A long wool coat is a classic no wardrobe should be without."

But, here it is clear that it means "without it" i.e., "without a long wool coat". In other words, the object is removed here as it can be sensed from the context. But, I am not able to grasp what should be considered removed here?

> The mind being every day informed, by the senses, of the alteration of
>   those simple ideas, it observes in things **without**; and taking notice
>   how one comes to an end, and ceases to be, and another begins to exist
>   which was not before; reflecting also on what passes within itself,
>   and observing a constant change of its ideas, sometimes by the
>   impression of outward objects on the senses, and sometimes by the
>   determination of its own choice; and concluding from what it has so
>   constantly observed to have been, that the like changes will for the
>   future be made in the same things, by like agents, and by the like
>   ways, considers in one thing the possibility of having any of its
>   simple ideas changed, and in another the possibility of making that
>   change; and so comes by that idea which we call power. (1690, Chapter
>   XXI, Section 1, pp. 219–220)

Comment: In passing, your interpretation of the "_wool coat_" sentence is, I think, not quite right. It is not "missing" an "_it_" (add it in, and the sentence sounds wrong, although "_A long wool coat is a classic: no wardrobe should be without one._" and variants would work). Instead, it is simply a slightly archaic word order. The "natural" version might be "_No wardrobe should be without a long wool coat_", although it is harder to weave the notion "_being a classic_" into this order ("_...the classic long wool coat._" doesn't, to me, have the same subtlety as the original).

Comment: btw, it should be 'an **excerpt** from', not 'an encrypt from'. Encryption is what the internet does for cyber-security.

Comment: There is a reduced relative pronoun '[that]' following 'classic', and it is also the antecedent of the *trace* that follows 'without'.

Comment: @TripeHound: There's nothing archaic about the word order; it's the same word order as found in, say, "a person I talked to".

Comment: @ruakh You're right, "archaic" was probably the wrong word to use.

Answer (score 15):

A clue is the later phrase *within itself*. You might guess from this phrase that the object of *without* is *itself*, and that *without* is the opposite of *within*.

And indeed, this is correct; here, *without* takes on its former meaning of *outside*. From [Oxford Dictionaries Online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/without):

> 2. *literary, archaic* Outside. *‘the barbarians without the gates’*

So what it means here is *things outside the mind*.

If you're reading things written in 1690, you have to watch out for words whose meanings have changed. The *Cambridge Dictionary* seems not to even mention this meaning, which I would guess means that it's not the best dictionary for looking up words from 1690. (In defense of the *Cambridge Dictionary*, this meaning is virtually never seen in today's English.)

Comment: Exactly:  you beat me to it.

Comment: @Peter Shor
Thank you Sir! It really made it clear. I am hopeful to get help from you in future as well.

Comment: The Beatles play on this dual meaning in their song *Within You Without You*.

Comment: One council ward in the [City of London](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/City_of_London) retains this use: [Farringdon Without](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farringdon_Without), whose name indicates that it was once outside the city wall - as opposed to [Farringdon Within](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farringdon_Within).

Comment: This meaning is still seen occasionally, in the set phrase ***within and without*** meaning "inside and outside (of)".

Comment: `If you're reading things written in 1690, you have to watch out for words whose meanings have changed.` And if you're reading things written in ***2018***, you have to watch out for people whose usage of the word "whose" is incorrect. :^)

Comment: "Without" in this sense is literary or archaic in standard British English, but in Scottish English, "outwith" is commonly used with the same meaning.

Comment: _"So the dismal Mole, wet without and ashamed within,..."_ Kenneth Grahame, The Wind in the Willows (1908) - not even that archaic...

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking at an old meaning of "without" here, namely, "outside" or "external". The only online reference I could find at a quick search was in the [LEO English-German online dictionary](https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/without):

> without (obsolete, poetic): outside (preposition)

This makes sense, since Locke is talking about the distinction between the mind and the information it receives from the outside world - the "things without" - through the senses.

Answer (score 2):

It's just the opposite of "within": "The mind... observes in things outside itself."

From the [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/229679#eid14185830):

> WITHOUT
>   A. *adv.* Outside, in various senses: opposed to WITHIN *adv*.   Now only *literary* and somewhat *arch[aic]*.
>
> 1. On the outside or outer surface (of a material thing); externally.

<sub>In this sense of the word, it's perfectly reasonable for your wardrobe to be without a long wool coat; what would be ridiculous would be to have your wardrobe *within* your long wool coat!</sub>